# Regular expression for Canadian SIN (Social Insurance Number)

Tags: .net, regex

`^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$` matches `111-111-111`

and `^\d{9}$` matches `111111111`

How do I write the regular expression so it would find a match for both of these inputs?

Comment: Why the down votes?  And I indicated the language (.net) and it's been edited....

Comment: Canadian SIN #'s use the LUHN algorithm. A simple regex cannot validate them properly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an alternative:

```
^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})|(\d{9})$
```

Comment: to add to this - i changed ^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})|(\d{3} \d{3} \d{3})|(\d{9})$ which allows for spaces such as 111 111 111

Comment: it's getting quite long now. with your changing requirements you might like my answer for maintenance and readability

Answer (score 1):

Just make the dashes optional

`^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}$`

Howeve that would also allow

111-111111 or 111111-111

Honestly though, you're better off just stripping the dashes, and validating `^\d{9}$`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but in a fast try I came to:

```
^\d{3}(-|){1}\d{3}(-|){1}\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for .net as it supports capture groups. So use a capture group to enforce just the cases of both dashes or none

```
^\d{3}(-?)\d{3}\1\d{3}$
```

and since you mention spaces now in a comment then the first capture group `-?` simply becomes `[ -]?` like this and you can tweak that capture group as needed and it will continue to require balance:

```
^\d{3}([- ]?)\d{3}\1\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work the best so far:

```
\b(?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})\b|\b(?:\d{3} \d{3} \d{3})\b
```

Looks for hyphens or spaces between 3 sets of 3 numbers.